# Is the following $f:S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ an embedding?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, submanifold

I have $f:S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ given by
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{(x_1, x_1x_3, x_2, x_2x_3)}{1+x_3^2}$$
If I am not wrong, the map above is an injective immersion.
I wanted to check if it is or not an embedding.

I argued that *f* is not an embedding since it is not a homeomorphism onto its image. Is it the correct way of reasoning?

Comment: For what reason isn't $f$ an homeomorphism onto its image?

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, I know. But this is more a problem of injectivity, which, according to OP, has already been shown...

Comment: @Didier: Ah, I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a classical result saying this:

> A proper injective immersion is an embedding.

As $S^2$ is compact and $f$ continuous, if $B$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $S^2$, hence compact. This says that $f$ is proper.

Thus, one cannot expect $f$ to be an injective immersion without it being an embedding: your reasoning isn't correct.

Comment: Easier yet: A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. OP should learn this well.

Comment: You are right. In fact, this is more or less the same result, as by definition, homeomorphism onto its image = immersion = embedding, isn't it?

Comment: The properness criterion is, to me, relevant precisely in the non-compact case.